# Tolstoy's "A Letter to a Hindu" - Krishna Quote References?

Tags: identification-request, leo-tolstoy

In Tolstoy's letter to Gandhi ([A Letter to a Hindu](http://raoinseattle.com/library/06%20Ganesha/Tolstoy%20Leo%20and%20Gandhi%201909%20correspondence.pdf#page=12)), Tolstoy quotes extensively from Krishna.

On page 12 above, Gandhi asks for the reference: "In the letter in question, you have quoted largely from Krishna and given reference to passages. I should thank you to give me the title of the book from which the quotations have been made." Tolstoy replies: "The Moscow people
will let you know the title of the book on Krishna," but the reference is never made explicit.

Has anyone located the source of these quotes?

Answer (score 4):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Letter_to_a_Hindu):

> "A Letter to a Hindu" (also known as "A Letter to a Hindoo") was a
> letter written by Leo Tolstoy to [Tarak Nath Das](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarak_Nath_Das) on 14 December 1908...
>
> The letter caused the young Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi to write to
> the world-famous Tolstoy to ask for advice and for permission to
> reprint the Letter in Gandhi's own South African newspaper, Indian
> Opinion

[Russian Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D1%83) elaborates further

> Материалы переписки Толстого и Ганди позволили исследователям установить, что все эти
> афоризмы на самом деле принадлежали кришнаитскому гуру Премананде
> Бхарати (1857—1914) и были взяты из его книги «Шри Кришна: Господь
> Любви» (1904)

Translation:

> The correspondence between Tolstoy and Gandhi allowed researchers to
> establish that all these aphorisms actually belonged to the Krishna
> guru Premananda Bharati (1857-1914) and were taken from his book "Sree
> Krishna. The Lord of Love" (1904)

The source cited is vol. 80 of The Complete Works of Tolstoy, *Moscow*, *1955*. This volume is [put online](http://tolstoy.ru/online/90/80/). The edition mentioned is Baba Premanand Bharati, «Shree Krishna. The Lord of Love», New York, 1904.

Recent edition is [available on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1372775161).